# React Filepond Loading Initial Images Not Working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, file-upload, filepond

I'm having some trouble using Filepond for React. Currently, I want to preload a user's profile picture when the page is loaded. I have tried two different approaches but none have worked yet:

First, I try to use the server load option of Filepond like so:

```
<FilePond
   ref={pond}
   ... other props here
   files={[
   {
     source: this.props.user.id,
     options: {
     type: 'local'
   }
   }
   ]}
   server={{
   load: (userId, load) => {
   fetch(fetchDomain + "/profiles/" + userId)
     .then(res => res.blob())
     .then(blob => {
        console.log('blob is: ', blob)
        return load
     })
   }
   }}
/>
```

I fetch from my express backend which is running on the same domain and returns an s3 image URL. This leads to an infinite loading situation and a picture is never loaded. I kept making small changes to this trying to fix it, but was never able to get it to work. At some point when I was messing with the code it would finish loading, but the image would be gray/unavailable with no error messages.

Another approach I took was simply setting Files to an image URL and this didn't work either. Same result, a greyed out image that I can clear it by clicking the remove item button. I did notice, however, that if that URL was a base64 url it would actually load the image properly.

I've been debugging this for a few hours already. Is there something I am missing here?

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but the setup at the top of my file looks like:

```
import 'filepond/dist/filepond.min.css';
import CropperEditor from './Cropper';
import FilePondPluginFileValidateType from "filepond-plugin-file-validate-type";
import FilePondPluginImageExifOrientation from "filepond-plugin-image-exif-orientation";
import FilePondPluginImagePreview from "filepond-plugin-image-preview";
import FilePondPluginImageCrop from "filepond-plugin-image-crop";
import FilePondPluginImageResize from "filepond-plugin-image-resize";
import FilePondPluginImageTransform from "filepond-plugin-image-transform";
import FilePondPluginImageEdit from "filepond-plugin-image-edit";
import 'filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.css';
const fetchDomain = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? process.env.REACT_APP_FETCH_DOMAIN_PROD : process.env.REACT_APP_FETCH_DOMAIN_DEV;

// Register the plugins for filepond
registerPlugin(
  FilePondPluginFileValidateType,
  FilePondPluginImageExifOrientation,
  FilePondPluginImagePreview,
  FilePondPluginImageCrop,
  FilePondPluginImageResize,
  FilePondPluginImageTransform,
  FilePondPluginImageEdit,
);

const pond = React.createRef();
```

Here is a picture of what the component looks like when loading after I got rid of all the plugins apart from FilePondPluginImagePreview and use the first method:

[It says undefined...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XP7hK.png)

After further reading of the documentation I'm now confused about whether I should be loading or fetching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was understanding the load and fetch features of the server object incorrectly. I had to get the image URL before and then use fetch or load within the server object in order to get the file from that URL and then convert it to a blob format. This would also work with an external server endpoint being called within the load feature of the server object as I was trying to do initially, but you'd have to make sure the server returns a file, not a URL. Well, I guess it could return a URL but you'd then have to do another fetch on that URL and then convert it to blob.

The answer to this question is what I did essentially.

[File Preview in React FilePond not showing up when setting initial file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61173840/file-preview-in-react-filepond-not-showing-up-when-setting-initial-file)